# Modifying AST of Elixir module before compiling

Tags: elixir, metaprogramming

Hello I'd like to build a library that replaces certain function calls with other function calls.

```
module A do
  def wrapper
    B.foo
  end
end
```

In the compiled program `A.wrapper` will actually call `B.baz`. I already stumbled upon the `@before_compile` callback but don't seem to get how I can change the AST of the calling module.

So all I got is this

```
module A do
  use Modifier
  @before_compile Modifier

  def wrapper
    B.foo
  end
end

defmodule Modifier do
  defmacro __before_compile__(env) do
    # Now what?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for [defdelegate/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#defdelegate/2).

You could also just create a macro:

```
defmodule Mofifier do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      import unquote(__MODULE__)
    end
  end

  defmacro wrapper do
    quote do
      B.foo
    end
  end
end

defmodule A do
  use Modifier

  def something, do: wrapper()
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify if the `@on_definition` attribute serves your purposes [here](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html#module-on_definition). Most probably it will.